# Filter out undefined property

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating over markers array and trying to filter out those places whose opening hours is undefined, however, I'm unable to filter out the undefined data. Below is my code and result:

```
const markers = data.map(place => {
      if (typeof place. opening_now != 'undefined') {
        return {
          position: place.geometry.location,
          content: place.name,
          key: place.id,
          opening_now: place.opening_now
        };
      }
```

> (20) [undefined, {…}, {…}, undefined, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
>   {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> 0:undefined
>
> 1:{position: _.F, content: "San Francisco Marriott Union Square", key:
>   "c904f2aae3fb8743f27bce36da94753a19b02131", opening_now : {open_now:
>   true, weekday_text: Array(0)}}
>
> 2:{position: _.F, content: "Cornell Hotel De France", key:
>   "547ceb15210b70b8734500183410bb10c644c395", opening_now :{open_now:
>   true, weekday_text: Array(0)}}
>
> 3:undefined
>
> 4:{position: _.F, content: "San Francisco Marriott Marquis", key:
>   "f007d2f91c0070ebdfec60275baa33623f0b771b", opening_now: {…}}
>
> 5:{position: _.F, content: "La Mar Cebicheria Peruana", key:
>   "2dfcc4cf449104804f979d0c74583f2b3a48d046", opening_now: {…}}..

Comment: you should use `.filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `undefined`s in your output data is that `map` operates on each element in the array. If your array is 10 elements long, your output array will also be 10 elements long. In your example you're just returning `undefined` (ie "no object") when your `opening_hours` is `undefined`.

> The [map() method creates a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) solution is quite tidy. It works the same as `map` but only returns the elements that satisfy the condition you give the function.

**ES6**

```
const markers = data.filter(place => place.opening_now.open_now)
```

**ES5** (which you might be more used to)

```
var markers = data.filter(function (place) {
  return place.opening_now.open_now;
});
```

It removes the `undefined` gaps in the array that you appear to have. This example, because you don't specifically express `undefined` also removes instances of opening hours equalling `null` if that's your bag.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/re8kyhpL/6/)**

Comment: Hi @Andy, how I can check 'open_now' property inside opening_hours key?

Comment: You just add `.open_now`. I've update my answer and the demo example. Note that this code assumes that `opening_now` exists in each object. If it doesn't you'll need to check for its existence first: `place.opening_now && place.opening_now.open_now;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only returning object elements from data then this should work:

```
const markers = data.filter(
    place => typeof place.opening_hours != 'undefined'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

first filter for defined objects, then for entries with opening hours.

```
const markers = data.filter((i) => i).filter((j) => j.opening_hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `map()` you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). `filter()` works like `map()` but instead of transforming values it will filter values by an `boolean`. If a condition returns `false` it will leave it out.

### Code

```
const makers = data.filter(place => place.opening_hours)
```

If `place.opening_hours` is `undefined` it will be convert into a `false` and `filter()` will leave this value out.